# Is value form mathematical operation column needed?

Tags: database, database-design, payment

Currently I'm working web application that implement subscription plan service and there is 'digital wallet' which is user can deposit or withdraw, and so the wallet can be used pay the subscription plan as well.

My question is "to track wallet balance, is needed to store the balance into column at user table or I just track the transaction deposit - withdrawal - subscription payment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually implement both options. I keep all transaction history, make sure it does not change (ever), and update balance at users table after each transaction is posted.

This way you have quick reads (you display balance without going through transaction history) and you still have all data in case something goes wrong.

Comment: Yes, currently I used that model, I just worried if my approach goes wrong or ineffective, thanks..